# Обновление текста в метке

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Имеется успешно объявленный и работающий stepper, а также метка

```
stepper = new Stepper { Maximum = 10, Minimum = 0, Increment = 1, Value = 0};
label1 = new Label { Text = "Вы выбрали 0 час(ов)"};
```

Хочу добиться того, что при изменении в stepper, менялся и текст метки (число в ней)

```
private void ChangeText(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (stepper.Value != 0) {
            label1.Text = String.Format("Вы выбрали {0} час(ов)", stepper.Value);
        }
    }
```

Пытался сделать так, но не знаю как вызвать этот метод. 
Следующая запись выдает ошибку,

```
 label1.Text += ChangeText;
```

**System.ArgumentException:** 'Value is an invalid value for Minimum

Comment: Научитесь использовать привязки! У вас было бы свойство `public int StepValue {get;set;}`, которое привязано к `Stepper` (созданном в XAML!) `<Stepper Maximum = "10" Value = "{Binding StepValue}" />`, дальше вам достаточно будет его привязать еще и к `Lable` с указанием нужного вида, что то по типу  `<Lable Text = "{Binding StepValue, StringFormat=Вы выбрали {}{0} час(ов)}" />` и все, вот весь ваш код, останется только задать где то `DataContext` и поместить все по своим местам. А текущий ваш подход, он ужасен (ИМХО).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Ваш комментарий возможно полезен, но не помогает решить текущую проблему. Я попробовал использовать привязки по примеру найденному в интернете, но значение не менялось. Не могли бы вы привести пример кода, который бы в данном случае работал?

Comment: `значение не менялось` - понятие растяжимое. Если хотите, оформляйте новый вопрос, прикладывайте туда все ваши попытки и что в итоге получаете, разберемся. Код я вам давать не буду, ибо во первых у меня нет сейчас Xamarin, а во вторых в интернете полно уроков по MVVM, привязкам и прочим тонкостям. P.S. Моя задача не ответить вам, а направить на правильный путь, ибо с таким подходом вы дальше на SO будете задавать сотни подобных вопросов и все потому, что пишете "костылями" (мое ИМХО).

Answer (score 0):

Код ниже позволяет изменяться тексту в метке, в процессе работы

```
private void ChangeText(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e) {
        label1.Text = String.Format("Вы выбрали {0} час(ов)", (int)stepper.Value);
    }
```